Mesh Clipping glitch in Blender 4.2, even with Clip Start set to .001, is there a way to fix this?
I am trying to apply materials in a huge scene(Specifically Telltale's: The Walking Dead Season 2 Ski Lodge Environment, which I exported as a FBX from 3DSMax). in Blender 4.2 and I'm having an issue of the mesh clipping itself and glitching, even though the Clip Start is set to .001.
Is there a way to fix this so I can just start applying materials?


Clip Start and End have function beyond just clipping content; they control the resolution used by the z-buffer that sorts which objects are visible and which are hidden. By setting your clip plane end to that enormous number, you've made it so that the 3D engine is having trouble determining which content is in front of which.
It can be forgiving, but there are limits. With an enormous _Clip End _value, notice how increasingly small Clip Start values cause worse and worse rendering:

Lower your Clip Start and Clip End values to something reasonable, and I believe that will fix the problem you are seeing. I don't see any near-clip problems in your image, only z-buffer tearing.
